# How can I build a face detection aplication by implementing my own CNN and train it from scratch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

The aplication only takes some images and draws some rectangles around the faces that are present there.
I used some CNNs made in Python with keras for image classification Face and NonFace here are the types of images that I used  [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Nd79MI55i3u6_BBlXSLWF8BCwpiMYqsy?usp=sharing) . My only problem is that I don't quite understand how to use a CNN to detect MULTIPLE faces from an image, I tried to verify every frame of an image but that takes to much time and it's not good at all. Can I train a model to actually return the location of my face or do I have to make an algorithm that searches for the faces?
Thanks, any help would be much apreaciated.

Comment: This [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/face-detection-for-beginners-e58e8f21aad9) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have look at the YOLO algorithm, it uses a grid on the image and outputs bounding boxes, giving you location of the object.

Answer (score 0):

you can detect all the faces in an image using mtcnn. The code for that is shown below

```
from mtcnn import MTCNN
import os
import cv2
detector = MTCNN()
dest_dir=r'C:\Temp\people\storage\cropped' # specify where to save the images
filename=r'C:\Temp\people\storage\34.png' # specify the file name full path
try:
    img=cv2.imread(filename) # filename must be full path to the image
    shape=img.shape # will cause an exception if image was not read properly
    data=detector.detect_faces(img)                
    if data ==[]:
        print ('no faces were detected for file ', filename)
    else:
        for i, faces  in enumerate(data):
            box= faces['box']
            if box != []:
                box[0]= 0 if box[0]<0 else box[0]
                box[1]= 0 if box[1]<0 else box[1]            
                cropped_img=img[box[1]: box[1]+box[3],box[0]: box[0]+ box[2]]               
                fname=os.path.split(filename)[1]
                index=fname.rfind('.')
                fileid=fname[:index]
                fext=fname[index:]
                fname=fileid + '-' +str(i) + fext                
                save_path=os.path.join(dest_dir,fname )                
                cv2.imwrite(save_path, cropped_img)
except:
    print(' an error occurred')
```